# Netsuite: How to narrow “addMarkAllButtons()” to only include one set of buttons?

Tags: button, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I’m encountering a problem with the NetSuite “addMarkAllButtons()” call. Does anyone know of a way to reduce the call to only include a specific set of buttons? Or would I need to make a custom function/button to do this? Thanks!

[Image of issue with NetSuite's “addMarkAllButtons()” call.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeK0N.png)

Comment: I've had to make a custom button every time I run into this; it's very disappointing.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks, Eric!